# Run browser commands concurrently in Protractor

Tags: protractor

Is there any way to write a Protractor test in such a way that would allow simulation of many users at once? E.g. simulate 100 users all making a checkout at the same time, or 100 users all logging in at the same time. The purpose being to detect any possible race conditions or locking issues.

Protractor appears to be designed so that everything runs in sync, even across multiple browser instances (i.e. forks). Is there any way to accomplish what I'm doing in Protractor, or am I out of luck?

Note that I'm not referring to running tests concurrently (be that running tests under both Firefox and Chrome or spreading `describe`s over multiple instances to speed it up), rather the ability to spawn new "threads" inside one test case to execute commands in parallel.

Comment: Sole Protractor will not allow you get this done (I assume), but it seems like you need to find a way to mimic those users by sending API requests. Unfortunately I'm not ready to provide you with a solution, but look for options of sending API requests directly from protractor (i.e. using XMLHttpRequest), or I would say consider using Postman or the similar goal I believe can achieved with JMeter. The first tool is is for testing API, the second one for performance testing which I know for sure may send requests simultaneously.